# Spring boot, exclude dependencies from test in Gradle 5

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I want to exclude two jars from test and only use them when the application is actually running.

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    runtimeOnly('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
}
```

How do I explicitly tell Gradle 5 not to load these jars during the running of tests? I have already disabled their use but they keep getting loaded anyway. I was hoping for something simple like below, but I've been unable to find a conclusive answer.

```
test.exclude {
    group 'org.springframework.cloud'
}
```

EDIT

Copy paste solution

```
configurations.testCompile.exclude(group: 'org.springframework.cloud', module: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
configurations.testCompile.exclude(group: 'org.springframework.cloud', module: 'spring-cloud-starter-config')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your **dependencies** block, you can do something like:

```
configurations.testCompile.exclude(group: 'the-group', module: 'the-module')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works brilliantly and it's easy to maintain too